# Buses in 8086 micro-processor

Tags: microprocessor, bus, intel

What are the buses known as A, B, C in the following architecture of 8086? I cannot find any information about these.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the document the image is torn from explaining it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: 8086]

A-bus is the internal 16-bit **ALU data bus**.

C-Bus is the internal 20-bit address bus, 16-bit data bus, and possibly control lines of  the **BIU bus**.

B-bus has no true name but the function of the adder ALU is to add the shifted 16-bits (Starting Address of 64 Kbyte segment) CS (Code Segment) to the 16-bits IP (Instruction Pointer - Offset into CS for next instruction) to get the 20-bit Physical Address.  The right side of both diagrams allows the segment registers to be accessed.  I'd guess B-bus's name would be **Offset bus**.

From my explanation, it's clear why these names are not common.  They don't really correlate with the way the 8086 works.  Assuming A-bus means Address can be dangerous.

I'd read the page where you got the graphic.  It does explain the operation (as someone pointed out).  If there is no reference to something that is in a diagram, it's usually because it's a bit more involved than a straight correlation.

Comment: If the left side bus entering the "adder" is B-bus, then what is the right side?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://www.cosc.brocku.ca/~bockusd/3p92/Local_Pages/8086_achitecture.htm), "A-Bus" is referring to "ALU Bus". C-Bus is referring to "Control logic BUS". The B-Bus looks like just a name..

Comment: Seems like your explanation is more accountable as its reference is Intel itself.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, `A` stands for "arithmetic", `B` for "base" (e.g. array starting address) and `C` is the counter (e.g. array index/offset).

Comment: I was expecting them to be address bus, data bus, control bus etc.

Comment: Well `control bus` looks strange having no connection to `control system` at all.