# What is the name of this part in Intel 8086?

Tags: microprocessor, cpu, intel, x86

[image: 8086 Assembly's Diagram Block]
Picture is from [here](https://electronicsdesk.com/8086-microprocessor.html).

I am pointing to the block inside the BIU that I marked with a red box. There memory address calculation is performed, or conversion from 16-bits into 20-bits.

The shape is like an ALU's but inverted with a Σ inside. It is the only part in the diagram that has no name. For the sake of easy speaking when talking about microprocessor, I need to know what its name is. I have searched in many sources but I could not find it. Even in the link where the picture comes from the name is not mentioned, only the task it performs. So, what is its name?

Comment: the capital letter sigma represents `sum`

Comment: Pretty sure that's an adder. Like an ALU, only without the L and most of the A.

Comment: BIU and that site has a good explanation and drawing shows the math.  Offset is IP (Instruction Pointer), combined with appropriate segment (code, stack, etc.).

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, I am asking its name to easy speaking when talking about microprocessor 8086.

Comment: @Hearth, yes it is possible the name is adder. But what I am asking something like a firm confirmation so we may say it when talking or discussing 8086 microprocessor.

Comment: The summation symbol means it adds 16 bit segment address shifted to the right 4 bits  to the 16 bit instruction pointer to get a 20 bit physical address.  The physical addresss adder!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, Yes, we maybe safely say its name is "Physical Address (PA) adder" or "Effective Address (EA) generator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most generally speaking, it's a part of an address generator. Here specifically, it's just an adder.

Also, that 8086 diagram is a bit too simplistic. The address generator circuitry is a bit more complex than just a simple adder. 8086 has several addressing modes after all.

Comment: It is an adder and an address generator, that is true. Slight corrections needed. It is only the physical address generator of the bus interface unit (BIU), and it really is just that simple. Sure, it has to know which segment register to use as a base, but otherwise it does not deal with any addressing modes at all, as the offset, or effective address (EA), is calculated by the execution unit (EU), using the ALU.

Comment: We maybe save to say its name is either Address Adder or Address Generator. Probably no formal name from Intel.

Comment: @GrahamNye, thank you for your two links. Very informative.

Comment: @Justme, yes, it is physical address generator as already label in that diagram. It will provide address calculation which is called Effective Address (EA) or Physical Address (PA).

Comment: This earlier [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/167422/102667) shows some more internal detail, including temporary registers inaccessible to the programmer. The BIU doesn't have any more calculation ability though. The more complex address modes are implemented with microcode, using the ALU for calculations ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Performance)). Instruction execution times are extended by between 5 to 12 cycles to give time to compute the effective address, when needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is just an adder to sum up a 16-bit segment with a 16-bit offset to produce a 20-bit physical address.

Answer (score -1):

In simple words it's called a "**Sign extend**". Usually the address lines in a 8086 are 20 bits and physically available are only 16 bits (the processor).

So an offset is added to the segment address (16 bits inside the processor) to memory i.e physical address. Here is an image of what exactly the computation does inside sign extend:

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrPUK.png) Reference: Advanced Microprocessors and Peripherals – A. K. Ray and K. M. Bhurchandani, TMH, 2nd Edition 2006

Comment: It is not called "sign extend" because it performs a sum, not a sign extend operation.

Comment: Not a bad answer if you fix the sign extend.